# Polar Co-ordinate proofs

Tags: vector-spaces, spherical-coordinates

The expression for acceleration in spherical polars is

$$ \ddot{\mathbf r} =( \ddot r -r\dot\theta^2-r\dot\phi^2\sin^2\theta) \mathbf e_r + (r\ddot\theta+2\dot r \dot\theta-r\dot\phi^2\sin\theta\cos\theta    ) \mathbf e_\theta + \frac {1}{r\sin\theta} \frac {d}{dt}(r^2\dot \phi\sin^2\theta) \mathbf e_\phi 
$$

Hence show there can be a solution to the equation of motion where the particle orbits at constant latitude $\theta_0 $, constant radius $ r_0$ , and constant angular velocity $ \dot \phi= \omega $. Write down the constraints on the values of $ \theta, r_0,  $ and $ \omega $ .

---

Im really lost with this question, not sure how to begin, all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please, check if the editing of the equation is correct.

Comment: If constant latitude $\theta_0$, what can you say about the scalar $\dot\theta$? and $\ddot\theta$?

Comment: Will the first and second derivatives of theta be zero, since taking the derivative of a single constant gives us that?

Comment: @A.G. thank you, just what I wanted.

Comment: @mnmakrets I am a bit suspicious about the $\sin^2\theta$ in the ${\mathbf e}_r$ coordinate. Shouldn't it be just $\sin\theta$?

Comment: nope, just double checked the paper question, it says $ sin^2 \theta $ in the $ \mathbf e_r $ coordinate.   @A.G.

Comment: @mnmakrets yeah, that's right.

Comment: @mnmakrets There is a substantive reduction in the general equation given in spherical coordinates upon fixing $r$ and $\theta$, while holding $\dot \phi$ fixed.  Please see my answer for the details.  And +1 for the cool question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If both $r=r_0$ and $\theta=\theta_0$ are constants, then their time derivatives are zero.

That is to say, $\dot r=\ddot r=0$ and $\dot \theta=\ddot \theta=0$.

We also are given $\dot \phi =\omega$ is a constant.

Therefore,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d^2\vec r}{dt^2}&=\hat r(\theta_0,\phi) (-r_0\omega^2 \sin^2\theta_0)+\hat \theta(\theta_0,\phi)(-r_0 \omega^2 \sin \theta_0 \cos \theta_0) \\\\
&=-\omega^2 (\hat x x+\hat yy) \tag 1
\end{align}$$

---

> **NOTE:**
>   In arriving at $(1)$, we made use of the following relationships:$$x=r\sin \theta \cos \phi$$ $$y=r\sin \theta \sin \phi$$ $$\hat x=\hat r \sin \theta \cos \phi+\hat \theta \cos \theta \cos \phi-\hat \phi \sin \phi$$ $$\hat y=\hat r \sin \theta \sin \phi+\hat \theta \cos \theta \sin \phi+\hat \phi \cos \phi$$
>   Putting that all together, we find that $$\hat xx+\hat yy=r\sin \theta \left(\hat r \sin \theta+\hat \theta \cos \theta\right)$$
>
> ---

Thus, the equations of motion reduce to

$$\begin{align}
&\ddot x+\omega^2 x=0\\\\
&\ddot y+\omega^2 y=0\\\\
&\ddot z=0
\end{align}$$

from which we obtain

$$\begin{align}
&x(t)=\frac{\dot x(0)}{\omega}\sin \omega t+x_0\cos \omega t\\\\
&y(t) =\frac{\dot y(0)}{\omega}\sin \omega t+y_0\cos \omega t\\\\
&z(t)=r_0\cos \theta_0
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you, I don't quite understand how to obtain the $ -\omega^2 ( \hat x x + \hat y y)$ term. Is it a conversion from polar to cartesian coordinates?

Comment: Also in the first part of the answer, does the $ e_\phi $ term disappear because it initially had a differential $ ( \frac{d}{dt}) $ term in it that would make the whole $ e_\phi $ term equal to zero once evaluated?

Comment: @mnmakrets So, we have $\hat x=\hat r \sin \theta \cos \phi+\hat \theta \cos \theta \cos \phi-\hat \phi \sin \phi$ and $x=r\sin \theta \cos \phi$, while $\hat y=\hat r \sin \theta \sin \phi+\hat \theta \cos \theta \sin \phi+\hat \phi \cos \phi$ and $y=r\sin \theta \sin \phi$.  So, putting that all together, $\hat xx+\hat yy=\hat r r\sin^2 \theta+\hat \theta r\cos \theta \sin \theta$

Comment: @mnmakrets I've added a note to the answer to explain how we arrive at $(1)$.  On your question regarding the "disappearing" $\hat \phi$ term, you are exactly correct.  The time derivative operates on the term in parentheses $r_0^2\omega \sin^2 \theta_0$, which is constant with time by assumption.  Well done!

Comment: I've got it now, thank you!

Comment: @mnmakrets Pleased to hear!!  And you're very welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

If latitude and radius are constant, then  then all derivatives of them are 0.  If the derivative of phi is the constant, omega, then its second derivative is 0.  so the right side of your equation reduces to $$(0- r(0)- \omega r \sin^2(\theta)e_r+ (r(0)+ (0)(0)- (r \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \omega)e_{\theta}+ \omega' e_{\phi}$$

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. Would that then be the full equation of motion the question asked for?

Comment: Please start using LaTeX, see this guide: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference Almost all of your posts need heavy editing.

Answer (score 0):

$ \theta$ is constant, $ \dot \theta, \ddot\theta $ vanish

$$ \ddot{\mathbf r} =( \ddot{r} -r\omega^2\sin^2\theta) \,\mathbf e_r + (-r \omega^2\sin\theta\cos\theta    )\, \mathbf e_\theta + \frac {1}{r\sin\theta} \frac {d}{dt}(r^2\omega\sin^2\theta) \,\mathbf e_\phi 
$$

ODE is between $ r,t.$

EDIT1:

It is also known as the *Conical Pendulum* problem in steady state for pendulum fixed at cone vertex,mass circling on base circle $r_0$. An even solution is:

$ r = r_0 \cos (\omega t ) $ , $ z = z_0, \theta $ are constants.

Comment: Thanks, I just don't understand the last part of your answer, "ODE is between r, t ", is it something to do with ordinary differential equations?

Comment: I think he just meant that the only function in the above that depends on $t$ is $r$, i.e., $\theta$ is not a function of $t$.

Comment: I believe that $r=r_0$ is also given.  Thus, the time derivatives on $r$ are also $0$.